# How do I get my offset models to be at 0, 0, 0?

Tags: interface, origin

Apologies, I'm relatively new to blender and have inherited this model. I have tried <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and setting the origin points, but the model itself is still off-point.  This means when attempting to rotate, it's axis is about 0, 0, 0 rather than being about the centre of the image.

How do I get the base of the model to sit at 0, 0, 0?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome :). I don't mean to be rude, but what exactly is your question?

Comment: Oh god.  Sorry!! I've edited the post.  Basically I want the model itself to sit at the 0 co-ordinates rather than being offset currently - how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Switch to 'Edit mode' (<kbd>Tab</kbd> key).
2. Press <kbd>A</kbd> key. This will select all the verts in the model.
3. In Orthographic view (<kbd>Numbad 5</kbd>) move the selected group of verts over the orange dot (the origin).
4. Repeat this step in orthographic view for X, Y and Z.
5. Back to Object mode, select the model, choose *Object> Apply> All Transforms*. This just resets any scale or transform issues.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow - great instructions - i'll give this a go and feed back, thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to let you know this worked great for me! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In Sidebar (closed on your screenshot, default 'N' key), at Tool tab > Options > Transform, check Parents:

[image]

Then select only Node and Assembly~19063 empties and move it to desired position in supposed center of your object group. Don't forget to uncheck Parents! After that move only Node empty to scene center.